# the difference between application-prod.yml and application-dev.yml in a jhipster application

Tags: java, docker, logging, docker-compose, logstash

While configuring a jhipster application in order to send logs into logstash , 
and by following the documentation in the jhipster-console site, they require to configure application-dev.yml OR application-prod.yml, honestly, I don't understand the difference between them, I configured just app-dev.yml but jhipster-console doesn't work for me!!

any help, please  !!

Comment: Nothing specific to JHipster, it's purely Spring Boot configuration and profiles, please refer to their doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JHipster comes with two Spring profiles :

dev for development: it focuses on ease of development and productivity 
prod for production: it focuses on performance and scalability

I commonly use the dev during the development to testing phase. 
Then build my war files in prod profile.

For more references you could check their Profiles documentation in the link below. 
https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/

Comment: Can you also differentiate between application.yaml vs application-local.yaml? My pain point is where exactly is the segregation made between the appliance of these 2 files. Both seem to be applicable on local profile so why have two.